# Zend framework: how to pass creation options to services

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zf3

When registering a service in `module.config.php` like

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Path\To\Your\Service\AService => \Path\To\Your\Service\Factory\AServiceFactory,
    ]
]
```

I can't pass in creation options when calling the service factory neither in ZF2 (when the factory implements `MutableCreationOptionsInterface`) nor in ZF3 (via `$container->get(\Path\To\Your\Service\AService::class, $options)`.

Could anyone tell me how to pass the creation options to the services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MutableOptions` is currently only available on plugin manager instances; the service manager does not implement it. This is why you see the discrepancy.

Références : https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/issues/7

Sample : https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/zend-framework-2-using-creationoptions-in-pluginmanager/

COMPLEMENT

My solution is to add a method with a fluent pattern to the AService class :

```
class AService
{
    public function __construct(...)
    {
        //your code, you can inject variables from $container by AServiceFactory
    }
    public function setOptions($options)
    {
        // your setting from $options
        ...
        // fluent pattern
        return $this; 
    }
}
```

To use your service :

```
$container->get(\Path\To\Your\Service\Aservice::class)->setOptions($options);
```

Comment: thanks alain, could you tell me how to get around this issue?

Comment: You can examine the add-in added in the answer.